# Resolving slf4j multiple bindings, tracing which artifact is root cause?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, slf4j

I've tried to follow the other slf4j and other answers from the web to no avail.  I think my scenario is a little different.. I started with a maven spring-boot jpa app, all works good.  I am working with some company's sdk but it's not maven. They provide a jar and jar-with-dependencies. This package will be `com.example:theirlib:jar:1.0`

When I install standalone jar, it cannot find required dependencies. I tried to add them to pom but run into unsupported repository layout legacy.  The permanent solutions to this looks to be log4j related, without manually installing those jars.

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1, com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1, com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory: Unsupported repository layout legacy -> [Help 1]
```

But those were just the first build errors so I tried the jar-with-dependencies, which throws multiple slf4j bindings error.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/example/theirlib/1.0/theirlib-1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x.
...
```

I am struggling to find the correct artifacts to put in exclusions, if exclusions even works since the installed jar is bundled w/ dependencies??  This seemed like an easier path to solve than trying to include all the correct dependencies and versions for `theirlib` in this code. Alternatively, I tried to exclusions with the spring dependency but still fail.

First I looked at the dependency tree:

```
[INFO] com.crush.sample:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] +- com.example:theirlib:jar:1.0:compile  // jar with dependencies
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4.1208:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.30:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
[INFO]    +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.22.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO]    |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.10:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.20:test
[INFO]    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.0:test
```

And now try many combinations of exclusions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.crush.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>theirlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.1208</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Are you running from plain command line ? Which JDK version do you use?

Comment: mvn 3.6.3, Java version: 1.8.0_272.  I run both `mvn clean install` and `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using intellij , a tool which i often use is [maven helper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper)

this allows analyzing the pom and its dependencies visually ,
for example selecting the slf-api from the leftside will show all the paces where its used , if it is marked in white it means its a compile dependency

[image]

P.S
you must make sure "thierlibrary" was not shaded , otherwise you cannot solve it with normal maven exclusions

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by looking at the exploded bundled jar and brute forcing all the dependencies into my project pom and using the standalone jar. Everything is happy for now..